# select() timeout of 3s even on ICMP port unreachable

Tags: c, network-programming, select-function

When I try to connect to a server with a non blocking socket (so that i can use select() with a timeout parameter) i realized that on a connect to a port which is blocked by iptables with -j REJECT the select() waits up to the timeout parameter but at a maximum of 3s.. it doesn't matter that the ICMP port unreachable packet is really quick.

```
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
if (select(sockfd + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, NULL) == 1) {...}
```

In the above example the select() blocks until 3s if the connect goes to localhost:1234 and the port is blocked like described above.

Does anyone know why this timeout of 3s to get a "connection refused"? How could I tweak it (because I got an ICMP port unreachable after 0.02ms)?

Answer (score 1):

The socket will only become "writable" if `connect` succeeds. If you also want `select` to return on failure, you should also check for "error/exceptional" condition on the socket, i.e. pass the set as the third `fd_set *` argument to `select` too.

Comment: connect succeeds always (because of O_NONBLOCK) and will block in the select() block.. but to be sure:

`FD_ZERO(&rfdset); FD_ZERO(&wfdset); FD_ZERO(&efdset); FD_SET(sockfd, &rfdset); FD_SET(sockfd, &wfdset); FD_SET(sockfd, &efdset); if (select(sockfd + 1, &rfdset, &wfdset, &efdset, NULL) == 1) {}` this will also block 3s even if after 0.02ms an ICMP port unreachable arrives

Comment: Is it possible you've also firewalled icmp?

Comment: No because if i DROP the SYN request the select() will wait forever.. but look: `REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:6379 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable` and all policies are ACCEPT